# How to fix "while" to loop and php to build HTML table that only shows one result in HTML table and everything else with no HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using "while" to loop through my PDO database results, and I am using PHP to build HTML tables as long as results exist. When the query returns the data, the PHP code will only place one result in an HTML table and everything else outside of the table format. What am I missing in my code?

I have moved my table coding inside and out side of my while loop. I tried embedding a foreach loop inside the while loop, but it just returns 11 of each result and still only one in the HTML table format.

```
<?php 

public static function find_members() {

  /* -------------BEGIN PDO-----------*/
  if (!extension_loaded ('PDO' )) {
      echo 'PDO is NOT loaded!'."\n";
      if (!extension_loaded('pdo_mysql')){
          echo 'PDO mysql driver is NOT loaded.'."\n";
      }
  }
  try {
            // calling stored procedure command
          $sql = 'CALL `Members`()'; 
          //$sql = "SELECT * FROM members";

          // prepare for execution of the stored procedure
          $stmt = self::$database->prepare($sql);

        // execute the stored procedure
          $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

      echo     "<table class='membertable'>";
      echo "<thead>" . "header for table" ."</thead>";

            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

              $mejpeg = $row['photojpeg'];
              $email = $row['me_email'];
              $name = $row['me_name'];


              echo "<tbody>";
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>
              {$name}<br />
               {$email }<br />
              </td>";
              echo "<td>". '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ' .base64_encode($mejpeg). ' " height="120" width="" />'."</td>";
              echo "</tboby>";
              echo "</tr>";
              echo "<tfoot>";
                echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>"."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
              echo "</tfoot>";
              echo "</table>";

         }} else {
            echo "0 results";
              }

      } catch (PDOException $e) {
          die("Error occurred:" . $e->getMessage());
      }
      return null;

}
?>
```

**called on result webpage:**

```
<?php $mbs = array(memberPage::find_members()); foreach($mbs as $mb) { echo $mb;} ?>
```

I expect the php code to build tables for each of the results. However, the actual result is only the first record is formatted with the table tags while the other results have no table tags.

**MY FINAL SOLUTION**

***The PHP code:***

```
<?php 

public static function find_members() {

  /* -------------BEGIN PDO-----------*/
  if (!extension_loaded ('PDO' )) {
      echo 'PDO is NOT loaded!'."\n";
      if (!extension_loaded('pdo_mysql')){
          echo 'PDO mysql driver is NOT loaded.'."\n";
      }
  }
  try {
            // calling stored procedure command
          $sql = 'CALL `Members`()'; 
          //$sql = "SELECT * FROM members";

          // prepare for execution of the stored procedure
          $stmt = self::$database->prepare($sql);

        // execute the stored procedure
          $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt && $stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

/*INSTEAD OF ECHOING TABLES, I AM ECHOING <div> TAGS*/

      echo '<div class="head"><h2>Title of query results will go here</h2></div><div class="content">';

            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

              $mejpeg = $row['photojpeg'];
              $email = $row['me_email'];
              $name = $row['me_name'];


              echo '<div id="info">' .
              '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ' . base64_encode($mejpeg) . ' " class="textwrap" />' .

              $name<br /> .
               $email<br /> .
              '</div>';



      }
 echo '</div>';

             }} else {
                echo "0 results";
                  }

      } catch (PDOException $e) {
          die("Error occurred:" . $e->getMessage());
      }
      return null;

}
?>
```

***THEN MY WEB PAGE HTML/PHP FOR THE MAIN DIV search.php***

```
<div class="members">

<h2 class="hidden">members</h2>


<?php $mbs = array(memberPage::find_members()); foreach($mbs as $mb) { echo $mb;} ?>


</div>
```

***Then I managed the output to the webpage via CSS***

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*This <div class="members"></div> is already on the webpage and not being echoed from php everything below is called between the open and closing tag*/
.members {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto;
grid-gap: 20px 50px;
grid-template-areas:
"head"
"content";

}

.head {
grid-area: head;
display: grid;
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

.content {
 grid-area: content;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 grid-column-start: 1;
 grid-column-end: 2;
 grid-row-gap: 10px;
 grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

#info {
outline: solid;
}

 .textwrap {
   float: left;
   margin: 1px;
   position: relative;
   width:  auto;
   height: 160px;
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-repeat:   no-repeat;
   background-size:     cover;
     }

.info{
 grid-area: info;
}

.photo {
 grid-area: photo;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**The final output loops through the results and displays the results on the webpage with styling. It was far easier and more flexible than using tables.**

Comment: You are closing the table inside the loop. If you want all the content to appear in rows you should just have the `<tr>` and `</td>` tags inside the loop, and the `<table>`,`<tbody>`, and `<tfoot>` opening and closing tags outside the loop.

Comment: You also have some improper nesting of the `<tbody>` and `</tr>` tags.

Comment: @tshimkus Thank you for your feedback. Your recommendation was very helpful. It is nice to have a second set of eyes when you hit a wall.

Comment: Thank you for all of your responses. I have updated the code with my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but here's how I've done things in the past.

```
    <?php 
    public static function find_members() {
      /* -------------BEGIN PDO-----------*/
      if (!extension_loaded ('PDO' )) {
          echo 'PDO is NOT loaded!'."\n";
          if (!extension_loaded('pdo_mysql')){
              echo 'PDO mysql driver is NOT loaded.'."\n";
          }
      }
      try {
        // calling stored procedure command
        $sql = 'CALL `Members`()'; 
        // prepare for execution of the stored procedure
        $stmt = self::$database->prepare($sql);
        // execute the stored procedure
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt && $stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo '<table class="membertable">';
            echo '<thead><tr><th>Name/Email</th><th>Photo</th></tr></thead>';
            echo '<tbody>';

            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $mejpeg = '<img src=data:image/jpeg;base64, ' . base64_encode($row['photojpeg']) . ' height="120" width="80" />';
                $email = $row['me_email'];
                $name = $row['me_name'];

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$name.'<br />'.$email.'<br /></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$mejpeg.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }

            echo '</tbody>';
            echo '<tfoot>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>something 1</td>';
            echo '<td>something 2</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</tfoot>';
            echo '</table>';
        } else {
            echo '<div>0 results</div>';
        }

      } catch (PDOException $e) {
          die('Error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage());
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is the answer I went with. This fixed my issues. The only one I have to solve is getting them to line up side by side rather than over and under. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @WesHenderson Not sure what you mean about "... line up side by side ..." Can you share a screenshot or something?

Comment: The comment box doesn't allow me to add a screen shot. If you think of it as a grid, column 1 row 1 cell 1 will include the first record as the code echos above. Then column 1, row 2, cell 1 echos the second record. I would like columns 1, 2, 3 - row 1 - cells 1, 2, 3 to display the first three records, then start a new row. This would continue through the end of the loop then stop. Does that make sense?

Comment: ~~~
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | header1                    | header2                    | header3                      |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | name1                      | name2                      | name3                         |
    | email1             pic1   | email2            pic2    | email3            pic3      |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~~~

Like that?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to get good formatting with <pre> or ``` or ~~~

Comment: So I changed my approach. Instead of using tables to return my query, for this specific application, I am using CSS Grids. Doing this, I only needed to echo <div> tags, assign them classes, and set up the CSS to manage the output. It worked perfectly.

Comment: I updated my post with my final solution. CSS Grids, for this situation, are a far better choice than tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the proper way to return data from a function.

```
<?php
public static function find_members()
{
    /* -------------BEGIN PDO-----------*/
    if (!extension_loaded('PDO')) {
        echo 'PDO is NOT loaded!' . "\n";
        if (!extension_loaded('pdo_mysql')) {
            echo 'PDO mysql driver is NOT loaded.' . "\n";
        }
    }

    try {

        // calling stored procedure command

        $sql = 'CALL `Members`()';

        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
        // prepare for execution of the stored procedure

        $stmt = self::$database->prepare($sql);

        // execute the stored procedure

        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $returnDataOutter[] = "<table class='membertable'>";
            $returnDataOutter[] = "<thead>" . "header for table" . "</thead>";
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $mejpeg = $row['photojpeg'];
                $email = $row['me_email'];
                $name = $row['me_name'];
                $returnData = "<tbody>";
                $returnData.= "<tr>";
                $returnData.= "<td>
              {$name}<br />
               {$email}<br />
              </td>";
                $returnData .= "<td>" . '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ' . base64_encode($mejpeg) . ' " height="120" width="" />' . "</td>";
                $returnData .= "</tr>";
                $returnData .= "</tboby>";
                $returnData .= "<tfoot>";
                $returnData .= "<tr>";
                $returnData .= "<td>" . "</td>";
                $returnData .= "</tr>";
                $returnData .= "</tfoot>";
                $returnData .= "</table>";

                $returnDataOutter[] = returnData;
            }
        } else {
            $returnDataOutter[] = "0 results";
        }

        return $returnDataOutter;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Error occurred:" . $e->getMessage());
    }

    return [];
}

?>
```

**called on result webpage:**

```
<?php $mbs = array(memberPage::find_members()); foreach($mbs as $mb) { echo $mb;} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I am new to this, I am trying to figure out the $returnDataOutter[], are you assigning one variable two different values, or because it is an array, will php automatically pull them together into an array?

Comment: the `$something[] =` already adds on to array more and more arrays are created everytime you call `[] =`

Comment: I reckon `returnData` is waiting to get paid... no `$`.